# How to insert one table to another from another database with relationships in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my old database, I have 2 tables:

**invoices**

```
id
dr_no
customer_name
created_at
```

**invoice_items**

```
id
dr_no
item_name
created_at
```

That is a one to many relationship. An `invoice` can have many `invoice_item`. The problem here is that instead of the id of the invoice as the reference, the `dr_no` is used.

I'm doing a revamp of the system and want to transfer the old database to a new one and use the `invoice_id` as the reference instead of the `dr_no.

The current `invoices` table already holds `100k` records and instead of looping it an inserting it in the a new database, I used this code:

```
INSERT INTO new_db.invoices SELECT * FROM old_db.invoices;
```

This does the job but to also insert the `invoice_items`, I have to loop all `invoices`, check all `invoice_items` with specific `dr_no` and insert into new `invoice_items` table.

Is there a more performant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert into the new `invoice_items` table using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO mew_db.invoice_items
SELECT
    t.id, 
    v.id,         -- invoice_id
    t.item_name,
    t.created_at
FROM old_db.invoice_items t
INNER JOIN old_db.invoices v ON v.dr_no = t.dr_no
```

Comment: Amazing. Didn't know you can do something like this. It works. Thank you!